# Plus minus reversal in the post length decoration

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

Why does plus and minus not work the way I expect in the `post length` option

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, above]

\draw[red] (0,0) --node{5cm} (5,0);

\draw[teal,
decoration={moveto, post=lineto, post length={4cm}}, decorate
] (0,-1) --node{4cm} (5,-1);

\draw[blue,
decoration={moveto, post=lineto, post length={4cm+1cm}}, decorate
] (0,-2) --node{4cm+1cm} (5,-2);

\draw[orange,
decoration={moveto, post=lineto, post length={4cm-1cm}}, decorate
] (0,-3) --node{4cm-1cm} (5,-3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Four lines of different length with text]

Edit: Plus works as minus and minus works as plus in this option. My question is about why this is happening!? -And also if the behaviour can be corrected by other notation or adding extra code. A workaround is not really needed as it is simple to write plus instead of minus.

Comment: Does `post length=(4cm±1cm)` work?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Yes. This seems to work.

Comment: I wouldn't've thought that my proposal to ask a question about how to add dots to the ends of a plot would result in such intersting follow-up questions ... =)

Comment: @JasperHabicht Can you link the previous question?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner It started [with this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/669065/47927) out of which hpekristiansen extracted [a question about dotted ends of plots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/669065/47927) which finally led to this question.

Comment: The "connector" that appears in "4cm-1cm" isn't a minus; it's a hyphen.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: The node is not part of the problem, so I did not bother with math mode or `siunitx`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is basically the same as [Enforcing Order of Operations on Dimension Expressions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595736/16595)
just on an internal level of TikZ.

The value, for example `4cm-1cm`, simply gets stored in the key `/pgf/decoration/post length`. Somewhere in the decoration code it is retrieved via `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/post length}` and this is just a “dumb” replacement.

Somewhere [in the code of the decoration the expression](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/1a1880a880b456d9710c1d861628c6fccab749ef/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex#L63)

```
\pgfmetadecoratedremainingdistance-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/post length}
```

will be calculated which is

```
<some value>-4cm-1cm
```

which mathematically is the same as

```
<some value>-5cm
```

and *not*

```
<some value>-(4cm-1cm)
```

---

I'd argue that is somewhat of a bug in TikZ.
Similar things happen with the `delta angle` whose value is just subtracted from the `end angle` (when no `start angle` is given, of course). (See for example [another answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/666441/16595) where I'm using `()` around the ternary operator because that was doing very weird things.)

---

So you will need parentheses (the `{}` braces get stripped by PGFKeys)

```
\draw[blue,
decoration={moveto, post=lineto, post length=(4cm+1cm)}, decorate
] (0,-2) --node{4cm+1cm} (5,-2);

\draw[orange,
decoration={moveto, post=lineto, post length=(4cm-1cm)}, decorate
] (0,-3) --node{4cm-1cm} (5,-3);
```

or evaluate the result before the decoration code gets to it:

```
\draw[blue,
decoration={moveto, post=lineto, post length/.evaluated=4cm+1cm}, decorate
] (0,-2) --node{4cm+1cm} (5,-2);

\draw[orange,
decoration={moveto, post=lineto, post length/.evaluated=4cm-1cm}, decorate
] (0,-3) --node{4cm-1cm} (5,-3);
```

Technically, this will store a result without units in the key but this will get converted to `pt` again by PGFMath.

Of course, you can just do

```
\pgfmathset(length)macro\<something>{4cm±1cm}
```

and then use `\<something>` instead.

(A `\dimexpr` gets handed off to eTeX when PGFMath gets to it and since that is greedy it grabs as much as it can get.)

Comment: This is also the reason why you often see something like `-2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep})` in my answers. Sure, it works without the `()` with the default value of `.3333em` but not if you use a sum or a difference as a value.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use `\dimexpr` (introduced by eTeX):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick, above]
\draw[red] (0,0) --node{5cm} (5,0);
\draw[teal,
      decoration={moveto, post=lineto, post length={4cm}}, decorate] 
       (0,-1) -- node{4cm} (5,-1);
\draw[blue,
      decoration={moveto, post=lineto, post length={\dimexpr4cm+1cm}}, decorate] 
      (0,-2) -- node{4cm+1cm} (5,-2);
\draw[orange,
      decoration={moveto, post=lineto, post length={\dimexpr4cm-1cm}}, decorate] 
      (0,-3) --node{4cm-1cm} (5,-3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The plus sign isn't working either.

One way to achieve this is for e.g. by declaring a `counter` then either setting its value or adding and subbing numbers to/from it.

Here is your code with this implementation.

Every time I need the value of the counter I call `\the<name of counter>`, in this case it is named `l`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{math}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick, above]
\newcounter{l}
\setcounter{l}{5}


    \draw[red] (0,0) --node{5cm} (5,0);
    

    \draw[teal,
    decoration={moveto, post=lineto, post length=4 cm}, decorate
    ] (0,-1) --node{4cm} (5,-1);
    
    
\addtocounter{l}{-1}
\draw[blue,
decoration={moveto, post=lineto, post length={\thel cm}}, decorate
] (0,-2) --node{4cm+1cm} (5,-2);
    
\addtocounter{l}{-1}
\draw[orange,
decoration={moveto, post=lineto, post length={\thel cm}}, decorate
 ] (0,-3) --node{4cm-1cm} (5,-3);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 I can also just write plus instead of minus. My goal is to understand why. -see edit. A counter is an integer, so a length is more suitable.